# OpenCV identify person with face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I would like to identify people through face detection. I found that OpenCV implements a method to detect faces but nothing on how to recognize a specific person!

Do I have to make a learning system like SVM to be able to identify people or is there an out-of-box function for that?

Thanks,

Comment: It can be surprisingly difficult to detect a particular face in a crowd. Take a look at this : http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/0.6/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html

Comment: [read a bit here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)

Comment: Yes, you will have to create a haar cascade and then train it so as to identify the face, the detection is the easy part, what follows is difficult.