# Passive and automatic face recognition

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition, openbr

Hy guys. At school we use badge for mark who is present, for my exam i want to upgrade that system. 
I would like to create a face recognition system, basically i would like to set a raspberry with camera over the doors, like that, when students pass the door will be automatically marked as present.

I know OpenBR but i didn't understand if i can use it for my project, and i have some issues with it, i can't install it, it return me an error when i test it.

I ask you if you know if OpenBR can do the trick for me (you have to know that we are a lot at school), or if there are some other technologies that i can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at using opencv to train an object detector to look for the badge:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEzm7L5zoZE

If each of the badges have some unique identifier for the students, you could then analyse the identifier to take attendance.

Identifying the badge / face would be the "easy" part.  Identifying the student would be the hard part!

Identifying people from photos is tricky, and I would estimate that Facebook has spent millions on this problem.

Here are a couple of links that may be useful

http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/0.6/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html

[OpenCV identify person with face detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467909/opencv-identify-person-with-face-detection)

Comment: Maybe I did not understand, I would like to use only face recognition, in this way, students can even leave badge at home, my project need only of the students's faces. I have to create a DB, where there are stored face with the code of the badge, when the camera "see" a student, the raspberry will send the message to school server and mark that student as present. I will study your links anyway, just in case, tell me if you have other suggestions dude!

Comment: So, you think my project in possible, the rasp will stay all the time recording, taking frames and recognize faces, is that possible? I have a lot of doubts, and i have to be sure to make this project, cause i have not a lot of time to make it, and i cant change it on run.

Comment: Without knowing your time frame: It is possible and detecting faces in general is quite easy. Detecting individual faces is a bit harder and companies have spent a lot of money on this.  But if you are willing to pay you could use a 3rd party sdk where the work has been done for you http://luxand.com/facesdk/

Answer (score 0):

You use Raspberry Pi for your project, so

**Software:**

**1.**[OpenCV-Python](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/) is a very good choice.

**2.** [SimpleCV](https://gist.github.com/mattgorecki/1096373) is more simple to use but less power than OpenCV. It's still ok for your purpose.

**Hardware:**

You also need to be aware of hardware, using USB Webcam is not a good choice because of slow speed.

[Module camera](http://openlabtools.eng.cam.ac.uk/Resources/Imaging/RPiCamera/) is better because it uses serial interface to transfer data.